# Has anyone ever tried to physically attack any of the Endless?

Tags: dc, vertigo-comics, the-sandman

There is one thing that always bothered me a bit in the "Sandman"/"Vertigo" universe: whenever one of the Endless shows up and introduces itself, people immediately assume that they are indeed what they say they are (Death, Dream, Desire etc).

But imagine a situation: A thug goes drunk from a pub, gets hit by a car and then he sees a woman telling him that "she is Death and he has to follow her". I definitely can imagine, that there would be situations, when the recently deceased would say "the hell I am!" and try to take a swing at the short, goth chick.

Has similar thing ever happened? I don't recall anything like this in the "Sandman" itself, but Death and Daniel (the new Dream) were present in many other DC comics.

EDIT: Just to be clear: by attack I mean "intend to kill, seriously harm or disable by using physical force". So attempts to grope Desire<sup>*</sup>, half-hearted slaps and using magic/non-physical superpowers (like telekinesis) won't count.

<sup>I've read it in a novel set in Sandman's world, where woman imprisoned by Desire tries to hug him/her", just to be gently pushed away</sup>

Comment: uhhh, Daniel... Right. Geez *hides in embarasement*

Comment: Are you including the bit where Dream was imprisoned for centuries?

Comment: @Valorum  No - Dream was imprisoned at least 3 times (once on Earth, once in his own realm and once...inside a Black Hole) but neither of those situations has been described as an effect of physical coercion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Corinthian tries to stab Morpheus near the end of issue 14 of The Sandman ("Collectors", from the "A Game of You" storyline). This does nothing to Morpheus and ends badly for the Corinthian.

[image: co]

Answer (score 4):

While not a sudden encounter like you describe, Nada slaps Morpheus hard near the end of *Season of Mists*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I mean probably some more serious "intent to harm"

Comment: @Yasskier - well, the other answer fits your bill, plus there's whatever happened to the first Despair, which had a perpetrator, but the details unknown.

Comment: Yes, the other answer matches the answer, I'm hoping to get some more info, maybe form outside of the "Sandman". Regarding Despair - we don't know how she was killed, it could be with a non-physical method (magic, act of god etc)

Comment: @Yasskier - Yep, that's why I didn't post it.

Answer (score 4):

Dream is shot at (repeatedly) in the [Sandman: Overture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sandman:_Overture). Suffice to say it's entirely ineffective.

[image]